# JSON String Will Not Parse

Tags: ios, json, parsing, ios5

I'm trying to parse a JSON string from a web service.  The string that is coming in looks like this:

```
{
"Faculty_Members": [
    {
        "ID": 3377,
        "First_Name": "John",
        "Last_Name": "Doe"
    }
]
}
```

My IOS Code looks like this:

```
NSURL *jsonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website/Service1.svc/Names"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonResponse);

//parse out the json data
if([NSJSONSerialization isValidJSONObject:jsonResponse])
{
NSLog(@"YEP");
  }else{
NSLog(@"NOPE");
}
```

The log will show the correct JSON data, but I keep getting "NOPE" on the isValidJsonObject.

The web service is sending the data back as datatype "string".  Does that make a difference?  If so, what datatype should i send it back?

Any ideas will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: i am try to parese same type of dic. and getting problem. @

NeedSomeAnswers if you get any solution and post it.

Answer (score 3):

You don't use `isValidJSONObject:` to test for a valid JSON string, you use it to test for an object that can be converted to JSON; See [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSJSONSerialization/isValidJSONObject%3a):

> ### isValidJSONObject:
>
> Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether a given object can be converted to JSON data.
>
> ```
> + (BOOL)isValidJSONObject:(id)obj
> ```
>
> #### Parameters:
>
> obj
>
> The object to test.
>
> #### Return Value:
>
> YES if obj can be converted to JSON data, otherwise NO.

Instead, just use `JSONObjectWithData:` to parse the data as usual; if it fails, it will return an `NSError` in `error`.

Comment: So, does that mean that an NSDictionary is not a valid object to parse with?

Comment: @NeedSomeAnswers: I think it is; just make sure you pass the right options.

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible that the web service delivers the JSON strings in a wrong coding.

According to the [NSJSONSerialization Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSJSONSerialization_Class/Reference/Reference.html)!

The data must be in one of the 5 supported encodings listed in the JSON specification: UTF-8, UTF-16LE, UTF-16BE, UTF-32LE, UTF-32BE. The data may or may not have a BOM. The most efficient encoding to use for parsing is UTF-8, so if you have a choice in encoding the data passed to this method, use UTF-8.

Comment: Thanks motou.  I tried the following code - NSLog(@"%@", [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"First_Name"]); but I get a message that says "unrecognized selector sent to instance".  And when i look at the keys of my dictionary, it says that I have none.

Comment: Can I encode is on the IOS side, or do i have to do it on the web service side?

Answer (score 0):

You should read up on JSON.
{ } indicates a dictionary.
[ ] indicates an array

So your returned JSON object is a dictionary containing an array containing a dictionary. To get the content, you could try the following:

```
// YOUR CODE
NSURL *jsonUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://website/Service1.svc/Names"];
NSError *error = nil;
NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:jsonUrl options:kNilOptions error:&error];
NSMutableDictionary *jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:&error];
NSLog(@"%@",jsonResponse);

// MY ADDITIONS
NSArray *facultyMembers = [jsonResponse objectForKey:@"Faculty_Members"];
NSDictionary *facultyMember = [facultyMembers objectAtIndex:0];
```

or even

```
for(NSDictionary *dict in jsonResponse)
{
    // parse contents of dict; perhaps store in temp object and add to 
    // mutable dictionary or array
    NSNumber *ID = [dict objectForKey@"ID"];
    NSString *firstName = [dict objectForKey@"First_Name"];
    NSString *lastName = [dict objectForKey@"Last_Name"];
}
```